# Select records from a table where one column value lies in another column in the same table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select rows from a table where a column value lies in another column value of the same table.
I am trying to execute code in Oracle SQL developer

I have a larger input dataset similar to below :

| keys | val | set |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | H | H, L , M |
| 2 | L | P, Q , R |
| 3 | P | P, S |

I want to select only those records where my val column value lies in the set column of the same table. There can be multiple or single values in the set column
The output would be like this :

| keys | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | H |
| 3 | P |

How to achieve it using MySQL ? Please help.

**Note **: **I have tried using below code. Its not working :**

select keys, val
from a where val in (set)

Comment: (remove oracle tag if you are only using mysql)
If the actual data is really as the sample shows, then checking if INSTR(set,val) <> 0 is enough, but if actual data contains words that may be subwords of the comma separated list of values SET then it will not work anymore (you may get false positive), you will need to use regular expression  (REGEXP) or normalize the SET column to be able to use a simple WHERE with equality check.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: BTW, are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a simple comparison using `concat` :

```
SELECT `keys`, val
FROM dataset 
where `set` like concat('%',val,'%');
```

Try it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/HZ5spY-k

Comment: Thanks @SelVazi, this is working and a easy to implement solution as well

Comment: Note that `like concat('%', 'John' ,'%')` also will return `Johnson` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's need something like:

```
SELECT keys, val FROM a WHERE SET='val'
```

Comment: I think this will work only for single values not for multiple

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
SELECT `keys`, `val` FROM `temp` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`val`, `set`);
```

Comment: this is not working :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ShubhiKaramveer it's working perfectly you can check here https://dbfiddle.uk/oTSCCgWm